# Using models from another package in forms in Spring boot - Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

In my `builds.html` page I have the following form:

```
<div id="deployment">
   <form action="#" th:action="@{/builds}" th:object="${build}" method="post">
      <textarea rows="20" cols="150" th:field="*{configuration}">
      </textarea>
      <br></br>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" type="submit">Deploy</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

my `BuildsControler.java` is in the `deployments` package:

```
import builds.Build;

@Controller
@ComponentScan("builds")
public class BuildsController {

// @Autowired
// private BuildsRepository buildsRepository;
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BuildsController.class);

/*
 * Add the builds url page
 */
@GetMapping("/builds")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("builds", new Build());
    return "builds";
}

/**
 * 
 * @param object
 * @return
 */
@PostMapping("/builds")
public Build deploy(@ModelAttribute Build build) {
    logger.info(String.format("--------- Deploying build: %s --------", build));
    return build;
}
```

}

while the `Build` model is in the `builds` package:

```
@Document(collection = "builds")
public class Build {

    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private String id;
    private String date;

    @NotNull
    private String configuration;

    public Build() {
    }

    public Build(String configuration) {
        this.id = new ObjectId().toHexString();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        this.date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
 }
```

So I'm getting the following error:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "builds": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "builds.build" (builds:514)
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "builds.build" (builds:514)] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 7): Property or field 'build' cannot be found on object of type 'builds.Build' - maybe not public?
```

How can I use the `build` model in the form, since `Build` is in another package?

Comment: Have you included your build package during component scan ?

Comment: @skm I've updated my question to include the full controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `build` not `builds`, when adding an attribute in the GET method, because you use `build` here `th:object="${build}"`, so Spring can't find it.

```
model.addAttribute("build", new Build());
```

This doc [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) may help.

Comment: @cybertextron Happens. You can now accept the answer. :)